# How to confirm Evernote Webhook being sent?

Tags: webhooks, evernote

**Goal:** Determine if webhook error is Evernote not sending notification or our server/software.

**Context:**

- Had a functioning webhook Evernote was sending (similar to below)
- We asked them to "add" another without knowing there is no "add" only "replace"
- Subsequently asked them to put back previous webhook and gave them webhook url and filter.
- Tested every permutation of original webhook, others we wanted to add and possible typo mistakes they could have made in entering it.

Example webhook (ids changed)
"Java/1...."
162.111.222.100 - - [22/Feb/2016:22:41:00 +0000] "GET /pages/webhookfunction?userId=1234&notebookGuid=1234e1-456-4c83-aeef-44f880f&reason=notebook_create HTTP/1.1" 301 348 "

**Result:**

- No webhook received since 1 minute before they notified us of the "add"
- No webhook when testing the new filter, old filter or anything.
- Checked server logs for anything hitting any url on our server and there is nothing in the form of a webhook, nothing from the IP of previous webhooks, nothing hitting the exact url except our tests directly hitting the url from Chrome.

**Needed:**
If our server logs aren't it, need method to determine whether webhook is being sent at all so we can troubleshoot on our end and not hassle Evernote.

Answer (score 0):

The server logs were accurate.  It was human error at Evernote which they have now corrected.